# Add different platform project reference to another project

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution with two projects, one is for Windows and the other one is for Linux.

Basically the linux project takes all the files of the windows project. (Right now I have a .vcxproj.filters and .vcxproj where I define the location of the files. For example:

```
<ClInclude Include="..\WindowsProject\file.h" />
```

The problem is that everytime I create a file in the windows project, I have to create every CLInclude, CLCompile in the linux project. I want it to be more 
automated. 
I have search a lot and I found that you can reference another project. But, if I try to reference my windows project in the linux project I get the following error message:

```
A reference cannot be added because the two projects target different platforms.
```

So I am lost and I do not know how to fix this. 
Any guesses? Hope the question is clear!

Comment: *"The problem is that everytime I create a file in the windows project, I have to create every CLInclude, CLCompile in the linux project..."* - That sounds about right to me, but I've never worked with VS on Linux. I help with a cross platform library. It uses a Makefile for Linux and MSBuild for Windows. I just edit the `*.vcxproj` by hand in a text editor. Its easier than trying to use the IDE.

Comment: You can consider use shared libraries or cross-platform library. http://gernotklingler.com/blog/creating-using-shared-libraries-different-compilers-different-operating-systems/ And CMake is also an option, but I can't speak for it myself. https://cmake.org/